# How to use outlook SDK for nodejs to send emails

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, outlook-2007

I have used custom SMTP to connect to outlook accounts as of now, but the issue is the mail sent via SMTP is not visible in sent box of outlook.

So i need to send emails using outlook sdk for nodejs.

https://github.com/jasonjoh/node-outlook/blob/master/mail-api.js

Is this the offical SDK ? If yes from where do i get token?

Need Help!

Comment: What specifically do you need help with in the SDK?

Comment: Also, have you considered BCC'ing the email to your inbox to keep a record?

Comment: if i put bcc it will show in inbox folder not in sent folder. I need to know how to use sdk to send emails and which is the offical sdk

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

> Generate a client ID and secret
>   Before we proceed, we need to register our app to obtain a client ID and secret. Head over to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com to quickly get a client ID and secret. Using the sign in buttons, sign in with either your Microsoft account (Outlook.com), or your work or school account (Office 365).

From this tutorial page: https://github.com/jasonjoh/node-tutorial

Comment: How do i get Office 365 tenant, with access to an administrator account in that tenant, OR an Outlook.com developer preview account.